# Azure Function Contentful Webhook Error in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I'm having problems trying to obtain the http response from the contentful webhooks. I keep getting this error:

> "The WebHook request contained invalid JSON: 'No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'JToken' from content with media type 'application/vnd.contentful.management.v1+json"

This is my function code:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"


using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Web.Http;


public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
  @json(body('formdataAction'));
  log.Info($"wjat");

  //    req.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

  log.Info($"Webhook was triggered!");
  string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  // BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.TolerantJson.class);
  dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);

  log.Info(data.sys);

  if (data.first == null || data.last == null)
  {
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new
    {
      error = "Please pass first/last properties in the input object"
    });
  }

  return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
  {
      greeting = $"Hello {data.first} {data.last}!"
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'contentful webhook'? Also, what kind of request are you sending to your function? Are you sending valid JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ReadAsAsync` is trying to use the default media formatters which by default only allows `application/json`.

You could of course just register to use the json formatter for the contentful content type as well, but I'd suggest suggest using NewtonSoft.Json and doing something like this.

```
string json = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Here is a complete function that works with a webhook from Contentful:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
 TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // Get request body
    string json = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    log.Info($"Read json: {json}");
     dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    string deserialized = data?.ToString();

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, deserialized);
}
```

Comment: The solution that worked for me was when you are getting the url to input into the contentful webhook, use the master (host key) instead of the default.